# PySide2: QMessageBox resizes when informatve text is changed obscuring progress bar

Tags: pyqt5, pyside2

I have a custom `QMessageBox` with a progress bar. When I change the info text of the message box (using method `setInformativeText`), the window resizes automatically and hides the progress bar.

See below for a working example. The version I use is: `PySide2==5.12.0`.

How can I prevent the message box from resizing?

When the info text hasn't been changed the message box looks like:

[image: before changing info text]

After I change the info text, I get:

[image: after changing info text]

Working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QAction, QMessageBox, QAbstractButton, QProgressBar, qApp, QPlainTextEdit, QDialog,
    QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication,
)
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, Qt, Signal as Signal, QStandardPaths
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon

class ShowMessageBox(QThread):
    SLEEPTIME = 0.2
    started = Signal()
    finished = Signal()

    def __init__(
            self, text, parent=None, minimum_time=1.0, maximum_time=120.0,
            cancel=False, callback=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.message_box = QMessageBox(parent=parent)
        self.message_box.setText(str(text))
        if cancel:
            self.message_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel)
        else:
            self.message_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.NoButton)
        self.callback = callback
        self.progress_bar = None
        self.started.connect(self.message_box.show)
        self.finished.connect(self.message_box.accept)
        if cancel and callback:
            self.message_box.buttonClicked['QAbstractButton *'].connect(callback)
            self.message_box.buttonClicked['QAbstractButton *'].connect(
                self.button_clicked)
        self.must_run = False
        self.time_left = minimum_time
        self.time_stop = maximum_time
        self.start()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        qApp.processEvents()

    def set_running(self, must_run):
        self.must_run = must_run
        time.sleep(0.01)
        qApp.processEvents()

    def run(self):
        self.must_run = True
        self.started.emit()
        while (self.must_run or self.time_left) and self.time_stop:
            time.sleep(self.SLEEPTIME)
            if self.time_left > 0:
                self.time_left -= self.SLEEPTIME
                if self.time_left < 0.0:
                    self.time_left = 0.0
            if self.time_stop > 0:
                self.time_stop -= self.SLEEPTIME
                if self.time_stop < 0.0:
                    self.time_stop = 0.0
        self.finished.emit()

    def button_clicked(self, button_or_id):
        if isinstance(button_or_id, QAbstractButton):
            self.set_running(False)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        qApp.processEvents()

    def add_progress_bar(self, progress_max):
        # add a progress bar if we have none
        if progress_max and not self.progress_bar:
            self.progress_bar = QProgressBar()
            self.progress_bar.setMinimum(0)
            self.progress_bar.setMaximum(progress_max)
            layout = self.message_box.layout()
            layout.addWidget(self.progress_bar, 5, 1)
            self.progress_bar.setValue(0)

        # remove progress bar if we have one
        if progress_max == 0 and self.progress_bar:
            self.progress_bar.deleteLater()
            self.progress_bar.setParent(None)
            self.progress_bar = None
        time.sleep(0.01)
        qApp.processEvents()

    def set_progress_bar(self, progress):
        if self.progress_bar:
            self.progress_bar.setValue(progress)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        qApp.processEvents()

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.message_box.setText(str(text))
        time.sleep(0.01)
        qApp.processEvents()

    def set_info_text(self, text):
        self.message_box.setInformativeText(str(text))
        time.sleep(0.01)
        qApp.processEvents()

def process_events(process_time):
    val = 0.0
    while val < process_time:
        qApp.processEvents()  # todo:test
        time.sleep(0.01)  # todo:test
        val += 0.01

def main():
    app = QApplication()
    mbox = ShowMessageBox('some normal text...', cancel=True, maximum_time=10)
    process_events(1)
    mbox.set_info_text('some info text...')
    process_events(1)
    # add a progress bar with a maximum value of 20; corresponds to 100%
    mbox.add_progress_bar(20)
    val = 0
    while val <= 20:
        process_events(0.2)
        mbox.set_progress_bar(val)
        val += 1
        # change info text to show effect on progress bar
        if val == 10:
            mbox.set_info_text('changed info text...')
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: QMessageBox has its own private layout management, if you want to add custom widgets, use QDialog instead. Also, while technically you're not directly manipulating the message box in the *actual* thread, it's still discouraged to create or access UI elements from a QThread object, even if calling the related functions from the main thread. Finally, using while loops and forcing update through QProcessEvents is not a good idea, as it still blocks *proper* handling of events, even if you stop "just" by 0.01s (which is still a lot). Use QTimer and better signal/slot management.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your reply. I've should have noted the the while loop and `qApp.processEvents` was to get the example going. It's not part of the actual code.

Comment: I see. Nonetheless, the example code should always try to reflect the actual behavior of your code as much as possible: while this may not be the case, we might have no way to know if the issue was caused by the modifications used for the example or the actual code. That said, the point remains: QMessageBox uses an internal layout management that completely ignores *programmatical layout changes* for various reasons (mostly to retain cross-platform compatibility, including appearance): it's a convenience class used for *simple* cases. For more complex scenarios, create a QDialog subclass.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks. Noted. I had looked at many other posts before I asked my question and the consensus was exactly what you wrote: it is a convenience class with its own layout management. The behaviour I see in my application still is a bug to me: the `QMessageBox` should not resize if I change the text of one of its child widgets. I did find a workaround for the issue: Instead of using method  `setInformativeText` to show the additional information, I append it to the 'main' text (method `setText`) delimited by a newline. I will upload my new version as the answer.

Comment: Yes, it *should* resize, and that's because those functions are "shortcuts" to alter the whole layout: for instance, `setDetailedText()` results in adding or removing the relative button whether the argument string has content or it's empty. Since the message box should try to optimize its size as much possible, and the layout might be very different depending on the content (informative or detailed text, icon, checkbox), all those functions actually destroy the current layout and recreate a new one. What you could *theoretically* do is to add the progress bar *again* whenever you change ->

Comment: -> any of the above. Be aware, though, that your approach completely relies on arbitrary grid positions, which is a wrong assumption: what you should do is to use the layout `rowCount()` to find the next row of the grid. In any case, dialog buttons should always be near the edge of the window, no other objects should exist beyond that limit (and I suppose you put the progress bar there because you weren't able to put it above). To summarize, instead of unnecessarily complicating things by forcing QMessageBox to do what you want, just subclass QDialog and use your own layout implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work using method `setInformativeText` without resizing issues.

I managed to work around the issue by appending the additional text to the main text, as suggested in [Qt5 - Resizing a QMessageBox](https://web.archive.org/web/20190910202435/http://apocalyptech.com/linux/qt/qmessagebox)

My updated (working) code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QAction, QMessageBox, QAbstractButton, QProgressBar, qApp, QPlainTextEdit, QDialog,
    QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication,
)
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, Qt, Signal as Signal, QStandardPaths
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon

class ShowMessageBox(QThread):
    SLEEPTIME = 0.2
    started = Signal()
    finished = Signal()

    def __init__(
            self, text, parent=None, minimum_time=1.0, maximum_time=120.0,
            cancel=False, callback=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        # trac:970:I couldn't get self.message_box.setInformativeText to work
        # so used '\n' to delimit main text and info text, see:
        # https://web.archive.org/web/20190910202435/http://apocalyptech.com/linux/qt/qmessagebox/
        self.message_box = QMessageBox(parent=parent)
        self.set_text(text)
        if cancel:
            self.message_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel)
        else:
            self.message_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.NoButton)
        self.callback = callback
        self.progress_bar = None
        self.started.connect(self.message_box.show)
        self.finished.connect(self.message_box.accept)
        if cancel and callback:
            self.message_box.buttonClicked['QAbstractButton *'].connect(callback)
            self.message_box.buttonClicked['QAbstractButton *'].connect(
                self.button_clicked)
        self.must_run = False
        self.time_left = minimum_time
        self.time_stop = maximum_time
        self.start()

    def set_running(self, must_run):
        self.must_run = must_run

    def run(self):
        self.must_run = True
        self.started.emit()
        while (self.must_run or self.time_left) and self.time_stop:
            time.sleep(self.SLEEPTIME)
            if self.time_left > 0:
                self.time_left -= self.SLEEPTIME
                if self.time_left < 0.0:
                    self.time_left = 0.0
            if self.time_stop > 0:
                self.time_stop -= self.SLEEPTIME
                if self.time_stop < 0.0:
                    self.time_stop = 0.0
        self.finished.emit()

    def button_clicked(self, button_or_id):
        if isinstance(button_or_id, QAbstractButton):
            self.set_running(False)

    def add_progress_bar(self, progress_max):
        # add a progress bar if we have none
        if progress_max and not self.progress_bar:
            self.progress_bar = QProgressBar()
            self.progress_bar.setMinimum(0)
            self.progress_bar.setMaximum(progress_max)
            layout = self.message_box.layout()
            # line up progress bar with main text in column 1
            layout.addWidget(self.progress_bar, 5, 1)
            # set initial value
            self.set_progress_bar(0)
        # remove progress bar if we have one
        if progress_max == 0 and self.progress_bar:
            self.progress_bar.deleteLater()
            self.progress_bar.setParent(None)
            self.progress_bar = None

    def set_progress_bar(self, progress):
        if self.progress_bar:
            self.progress_bar.setValue(progress)
            # force update of message box in GUI
            time.sleep(0.01)
            qApp.processEvents()

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.main_text = str(text)
        self.output_text()

    def set_info_text(self, text):
        self.info_text = str(text)
        self.output_text()

    def output_text(self):
        try:
            text = self.main_text
        except AttributeError:
            self.main_text = ''
            text = self.main_text
        try:
            if self.info_text:
                text = text + '\n' + self.info_text
        except AttributeError:
            self.info_text = ''
        self.message_box.setText(text)
        # force update of message box in GUI
        time.sleep(0.01)
        qApp.processEvents()

def main():
    app = QApplication()
    mbox = ShowMessageBox('some normal text...', cancel=True, maximum_time=10)
    mbox.set_info_text('some info text...')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    # add a progress bar with a maximum value of 20; corresponds to 100%
    mbox.add_progress_bar(20)
    val = 0
    while val <= 20:
        # sleeping mimics application processing
        time.sleep(0.2)
        mbox.set_progress_bar(val)
        val += 1
        # change informative text while progress meter is active
        if val == 10:
            mbox.set_info_text('changed info text...')
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```